# The argument type 'bool' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

how do i fix this error? I want to call the return of my provider.
in this way but it returns me the error mentioned in the title.

```
IconButton(
   icon: Heart.isActive,
    onPressed: () {
     setState(() {
      Heart.changeState();
         });
                            },
```

try to remove the datatype from the getter, but it throws errors in the model.

```
get isActive => _isActive;
```

here the complete provider

```
class HeartIconState with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isActive = false;

  bool get isActive => _isActive;

  set isActive(bool value) {
    _isActive = value;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void changeState() {
    isActive //inicia en false
        ? const Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        : const Icon(
            Icons.favorite_border,
            color: Colors.red,
          );

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: "icon" must be a widget, not a bool.  Perhaps you want something with a ternary, like "isActive? Heart.isActive : Heart.isInactive"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats obviously clear that your passing `bool` which named as isActive
Instead of passing that use your function

```
Icon isActiveIcon() {
    return isActive
    ? const Icon( 
        Icons.favorite, 
        color: Colors.red) 
    : const Icon( 
        Icons.favorite_border, 
        color: Colors.red);
}
```

Now use it instead of your Icon

```
icon: Heart.isActiveIcon(),
```

You need to refactor changeState too

```
void changeState() { 
    isActive = !isActive; 
    notifyListeners(); 
}
```

Comment: the first code goes inside the provider model?
that gives an error.i dont understand

Comment: Yes under your changeState() write this and call in your iconbutton

Comment: all icons are marked at the same time :( :( :( :( :(

Comment: because you are using this function in loop, but does it work?

Comment: :( if I will mark it as successful :(

Comment: you need to make a model and list of that model, then in your listview you need to change that list item by index and there you just change one of items

Comment: I know you already solved my question but do you have a link to guide me? To be truthful, I did not understand you? please please

Comment: yes sure, follow this article https://souravsarkaremon16.medium.com/create-a-simple-todo-app-with-flutter-provider-ffabfe4c9d2f , this is example of todo app, you need to change it as you desire

Comment: i really appreciated that god bless you<3